# Why Laravel cannot subscribe to PrivateChannel over Laravel Echo?

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

In my Laravel 8 project, I use [laravel-websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/getting-started/introduction) to send messages over websocket, [laravel echo](https://github.com/laravel/echo) to receive messages. If I use Channel class for broadcasting, everything works great whereas I use PrivateChannel, socket connection can be established, yet no subscription is done. Hence I cannot send/receive message over websocket, but ping/pong messages can be seen on inspector of browser.

Most of stackoverflow questions were replied according to static named channels, but I have dynamic named channels that belongs to each users.

You can see my related code blocks below.

**<app.php>**

```
App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider::class //ADDED-to providers
```

**<BroadcastServiceProvider.php>**

```
Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => 'auth:sanctum']); //ADDED-auth by sanctum
```

**<channels.php>**

```
Broadcast::channel('task-emmiter{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});
//ADDED
```

**<MessageManager.php>**

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    //Channel works, PrivateChannel not
    return new PrivateChannel('task-emmiter'.$this->receiver); 
}
```

**<websocket.js>**

```
window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'ABCDEFG',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    forceTLS: false,
    disableStats: true,
}).private('task-emmiter' + mainUser.id)
    .listen('MessageManager', (e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
```